# How to zoom the screen in windows 7 like in linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: windows-7, windows, linux, ubuntu, unix

In linux we can zoom the screen using Windows Key + Mouse Scroll. On windows 7 how to do it

Comment: Are you talking about the Enhanced Desktop Zoom plugin for compiz, installed by default in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

You can hold the Windows key then press "+" or "-", but it's not as good as on Linux or OS X.

Answer (score 3):

You can use 3rd party software to do that. My favourite combination is [ZoomIt](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897434.aspx) with [AeroZoom](http://wandersick.blogspot.com/p/aerozoom-for-windows-7-magnifier.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to zoom using winkey and mouse wheel you can try [this](http://kotbcorp.blogspot.com/2011/05/mimic-compiz-zoom-in-windows-7.html) script.

```
; Created By :
;     Ahmed Kotb on 27/5/2011
; licensed under :
;     Creative commons Attribution 3.0
;     http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/us/
; version :
;     1.0

; A small script that enables you to zoom in/out using the winkey
; and mouse wheel instead of winkey +/- on windows7 magnifier program

#NoEnv
SendMode Input
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%

;zoom in
#WheelUp::send #{sc4E}
;zoom out
#WheelDown::send #{sc4A}
```

Comment: This works rather well. What the post doesn't mention is that you need to install the interpreter for that script, called AutoHotkey (https://www.autohotkey.com/)

Answer (score 0):

For me (Win7) the Control and the mouse zoom do the same thing - certainly in Firefox and Foxit. Alternatively the Ctrl and +/- keys.

Comment: I believe this is different behavior from what is being asked, where the entire screen is zoomed independent of any particular application.  This is done through a compiz plugin installed and enabled by default in Ubuntu.

Comment: AFAIK the only built in way is Control Panel / Ease of Access / Ease of access Center  then enable magnifier which does the whole screen. I haven't found any controls for it yet though.